# Generic of typeAlias in Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, kotlin-multiplatform, type-alias

I'm having a design problem that is a bit hard to explain, I will try resuming it in steps:

**I'm**

1. Declaring an expect interface in common module
2. Type aliasing this interface to an **Android API** interface
3. Constraining a generic class in making my common expect interface an upper bound of the generic type
4. Trying to use the generic class in my android Module and failing because upperBound expected is the common interface and not the typealias one.

Is this possible? is there some KMM gurus that can help me with implementing this behavior?

If you didn't really understand the question, here is more context for you to better understand my situation:

I'm using `typealias` to be able to use `Parcelable` and `@Parcelize` in my **common module**.

So I have these `expect` declaration in my common module:

```
expect annotation class CommonParcelize()
expect interface CommonParcelable
```

And actual matches on Android:

```
actual typealias CommonParcelize = Parcelize
actual typealias CommonParcelable = Parcelable
```

Thanks to this I'm able to use the expect interface and annotation to make my object parcelable from my **common module**:

```
@CommonParcelize 
class Event(
    var id: String,
    var name: String,
    //More fields...
) : CommonParcelable
```

Here my `Event` object will be considered as **Parcelable** and I would be able to pass it in a bundle in the **Android module**.

Once that is said I want to use the `CommonParcelable` with making it upper bound of a generic in a class that is in my **common module** like so:

```
data class Marker<T : CommonParcelable>(
    val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double, val content: T
)
```

The problem is that when I try to use this class in my **Android module** like that:

```
val markers: List<Marker<CommonParcelable>> = listOf<Marker<CommonParcelable>>()
```

it fails with this error at compile time:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected:
CommonParcelable
Found:
CommonParcelable /* = Parcelable */
```

Which is logic because since I'm on **android module** it get a `Parcelable` type by the `typealias` but expect a `CommonParcelize` and the compiler doesn't recursively know that `CommonParcelable` will become `Parcelable` at runtime.